# Compare the return of a function with the user's entry Tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have a problem with this piece of code. I'm trying to make a program which it's going to calculate how many words the user is writing per minute. I don't know how to compare the random word from words_list with the user's input into the Entry field, and if these two words matches, increase the score by 1, but if the user's typed wrong the word, it should move forward but the score should remain the same.

Thank you for your answers!

```
from tkinter import *
import random


window = Tk()
window.title("Typing Speed")
window.minsize(width=300, height=300)

score = 0


def get_random_word():
    words_list = ["car", "wisdom", "child", "pepper", "dentist", "horizon", "dungeon", "mother", "will", "human", "few",
                  "music", "bicycle", "road", "follow", "big", "sure", "simple", "money", "true", "lead", "age",
                  "paint", "much", "if", "end", "the", "own", "clear", "possible", "watch", "port", "stay",
                  "there", "has", "house", "speed", "together", "earth", "pound", "correct", "far", "day", "snow",
                  "left", "start", "how", "gold", "in", "move", "late", "during", "began", "pose", "study"]
    random_word = random.choice(words_list)
    return random_word


def get_next_word(event):
    if user_entry.get() == get_random_word():
        global score
        score += 1
        word_label.config(text=get_random_word())


word_label = Label(text=get_random_word(), font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
word_label.pack()

user_entry = Entry(window, width=20)
user_entry.pack()


user_entry.bind("<Return>", get_next_word)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: btw usually wpm is calculated like this: `correct_characters_typed / 5 / minutes` so basically each 5 characters are counted as a word (because of the average length of a word) also I would suggest that you simply have a function that will get random words from the list and append to some other list or sth like that

Comment: If you want to increase the value of the global variable `score` in the `get_next_word()` function, add a `global score` statement to the very beginning of the function.

Comment: @Matiiss: That's not the kind of wpm this is calculating — it's not about character or word typing-speed.